# CocosSharp - using device camera as a game background

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocossharp

I am currently going through some game cross-platform frameworks and I really like the sound and look for CocosSharp.

However I haven't been able to find out if it is possible to use device camera in the game itself. In my case I would like to use whatever the device camera is seeing to project as a background to my game.

Is this possible with CocosSharp? If so, would anyone be able to point me to a code snippet / which class to work with?